# End time Value Not Updating when Start time or Duration change in Appointment?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am creating new appointment and select start time and end time and when i change duration of appointment end time not updating according to duration value.

**NOTE : Appointment form works fine.**

and in Information form the value in Start Time and End Time also doesn't auto populate as in 
Appointment form.

[image]

Comment: Are you using CRM 2013 on-premises or Online? I think there are some javascripts not loaded, try to check that.

Comment: I am using CRM 2013 on-premises. There is no javascript added to this form.